# How to open files (installer) with C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I want to create a installer with many programs for a quicker windows reset.
I can´t open the files i choose:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Process.Start ("C:\\vlc-2.2.4-win32.msi");
    }
}
```

It always come this: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

What´s wrong.
Sorry for my bad English and grammar misstakes

Comment: Is your Windows OS 32-bit and the installer a 64-bit installer?

Comment: no my windows is 64bit

Comment: I just ran a copy of just downloaded `vlc-2.2.6-win32.exe` on my 64-bit machine with your code and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting msiexec and provide the install file as a parameter.

```
msiexec /i {package|ProductCode}
```

[technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx)